# how to convert and run string to image (base64) xcode

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, base64

I want get string of image in way base64 from (php file) in server.

but I don't know what decode this string and convert to image and display in UIImage.

Comment: will u send that string once?

Comment: so I get string of image in way for loop from server and dsiplay in tableview cell (any cell different image)

Comment: if possible then get image url from server (in php file response) not get image base64 data. and use EgoImageView insted of UIImageView for display image in cell  [EgoImageView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your string"];

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithData:

[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlString]])];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Try this.....may be use full for u.

Comment: thanks my friend this code run image or decode string to image?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 1.0f);

 NSString *strEncoded = [Base64 encode:data];
```

**Decode as:**

```
 NSData* data = [Base64 decode:strEncoded ];;
 image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```